# When is Lights Out isomorphic to its solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Consider the group $G_{n, m}$ of all *solvable* configurations of the $n\times m$ game [Lights Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(game)). To clarify what I mean by this:

- Each element corresponds to some solvable configuration of the game (a configuration which can be transformed into the all-lights-off configuration by pressing some sequence of buttons).
- The identity element corresponds to the trivial or "solved" (all lights off) configuration.
- The group operation $x * y$ starts from $y$ and toggles all of the lights which are lit in $x$ (which is equivalent to inputting $x$'s solution into $y$).
- Every element of the group is an involution, so $x^{-1} = x$.
- The group is closed under $*$, because if $x$ has a solution and $y$ has a solution, then one possible solution to $x * y$ is just the solution to $x$ followed by the solution to $y$.
- Any configuration which is unreachable from the trivial configuration by any sequence of button presses is not an element of the group at all.
- Two configurations are equivalent when they have exactly the same lights lit, regardless of which buttons you pressed to get to that configuration (i.e. the group action doesn't "remember" the sequence of moves made).

Now consider the group $I_{nm} = (\mathbb{Z}/2^{nm}, \oplus)$, where $\oplus$ is [bitwise XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR). Let $f: I_{nm} \rightarrow G_{n, m}$ be defined as follows:

1. Write the integer in base 2, with as many leading zeros as necessary such that it has exactly $nm$ digits.
2. Start with the trivial Lights Out configuration.
3. If the $k$th digit of the integer is a one, press the $k$th button (using some arbitrary fixed numbering scheme for digits and buttons).

Each element of this group corresponds to a *solution* to the Lights Out puzzle, whereas each element of $G_{n, m}$ corresponds to a *configuration* of the Lights Out puzzle. The function $f$ describes inputting a given solution, starting from the "solved" configuration, or equivalently, it takes a solution and tells you what puzzle that solution solves.

It is immediately obvious to me that:

- $f$ is a surjection, because every solvable configuration can be reached by pressing some subset of the buttons exactly once each, and every such action can be written in base 2 in such a way that $f$ reproduces that sequence of button presses.
- $f$ is a homomorphism, because bitwise XOR has the effect of cancelling out any double-pressed buttons, and otherwise preserves all button presses.

However, I can't tell whether $f$ is injective or not, in general. If it is injective, then it is by definition an isomorphism.

$f$ being a homomorphism has a variety of interesting consequences. For example, it shows that we can cycle through all solvable Lights Out configurations in at most $2^{nm}$ moves (by using [Gray codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code)), and more generally, it lets us import lots of useful things from the world of bitwise arithmetic into the world of Lights Out. If $f$ is also an isomorphism, then we can immediately deduce that the Gray code upper bound is tight (that there is no faster strategy to cycle through all solvable configurations), because it is tight on the bitwise side of the isomorphism.

All of the mathematics I have been able to find on the subject of Lights Out is focused on a linear algebra approach to the problem, which appears to be roughly equivalent to the slightly larger group consisting of all configurations, solvable or otherwise, under the same group action. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(game)#Mathematics), for the $5\times 5$ case, there are four possible solutions for each solvable configuration. So $f$ is obviously not an isomorphism for the $5\times 5$ case, because it maps the integers corresponding to $N_1$, $N_2$, and $N_1 + N_2$ (as described in that article), as well as zero, to the identity element, and more generally it maps four different integers to each solvable configuration.

On the other hand, for very small examples:

- $n = m = 1$: $G_{1, 1}$ is just $C_2$, and the isomorphism obviously holds. But $C_2$ is the most boring nontrivial group that exists, so let's keep looking.
- $n = 1, m = 2$: $f(0) = f(11_2)$ and the isomorphism fails. By symmetry, this also holds if we reverse $n$ and $m$.
- $n = m = 2$: There are 16 values to check, but if we remove rotations and reflections, then:

$$
f(0000_2) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} \\
f(0001_2) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \\
f(0011_2) = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \\
f(1001_2) = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \\
f(0111_2) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \\
f(1111_2) = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \\
$$

In this case, it appears to me that $f$ is injective, and therefore an isomorphism. So there's at least one "interesting" case (i.e. a case which is not the trivial group or $C_2$).

**For what values of $n, m$ is $f$ an isomorphism?**

Answer (score 1):

**$f$ is an isomorphism exactly when every $n \times m$ configuration is solvable.**

Proof that $f$ being injective implies that every $n \times m$ configuration is solvable:

$\mathbb{Z}/2^{mn}$ has exactly $2^{nm}$ elements. Since $f$ is a bijection, the number of solvable configurations must be $2^{nm}$. But there are also $2^{nm}$ configurations in total, so every configuration must be solvable.

Proof that every $n \times m$ configuration being solvable implies that $f$ is injective:

When every configuration is solvable, there are $2^{nm}$ elements of the codomain, as that is the number of configurations in total. Since there are also $2^{nm}$ elements of the domain, $f$ cannot be surjective unless it is also injective, because a surjective non-injective $f$ wouldn't have enough integers (solutions) in its domain to cover all the configurations in its codomain (the domain would need to be strictly larger than the codomain for that to work). We already established that $f$ is always surjective, so it must also be injective.

---

**Corollary:** Let $H_{n, m}$ be the group of all $n\times m$ configurations with the same $*$ operation as $G_{n, m}$. From $f$, we can construct an endomorphism $g$ within the group $H_{n, m}$. Let $g(x)$ be the configuration that results if you start from the solved configuration, and press all of the buttons which are lit in $x$. Then $g$ is an endomorphism, by similar reasoning as we used to conclude that $f$ is a homomorphism, and if $G_{n, m} = H_{n, m}$, then $g$ is an automorphism, again by analogy to $f$. Therefore, we may investigate $\mathrm{Aut}(H_{n, m})$ to determine whether unsolvable $n \times m$ configurations exist.